# Git still adds and tracks folders marked in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a few folders in Git added in my ".gitignore" file. They contain over 100k files. Mainly images, tmp and cache stuff. What I need is to be able to commit changes to my code with out committing what happens in those folders.

I thought adding them into the ".gitignore" would do the trick but for some reason it's not working at all. I haven't been able to commit anything to the repo in days because every time I try the push command it tries sending 100k files then it freezes and times out.

```
root@serveur [/home/***/***]# git push origin master
Password:
Counting objects: 110300, done.
```

How can I force Git to reindex the tree while taking in consideration the ignored folders so I can finally commit all the changes I made to the code?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is (probably) because you added some of those files before you added the `.gitignore` - so you have to remove them from git before they're able to be ignored.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/2128691

First, **commit any outstanding code changes**, and then, run this command:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

This removes everything from the *index*, then just run:

```
git add .
```

Commit it:

```
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

Comment: Please note that the commits including those files from **before that commit** will still be there. So this will not make your repository any smaller, instead git will stop tracking those files **in the future**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! perfectly explained.

Comment: Does it keep git history alive? git .add looks like it starts new history. What git rm -r --cached does with historical comits?

Comment: @Čamo see the first comment - historical commits will remain.

Comment: this doesn't work, git still tries to push files in .gitignore

Comment: @SarimMehdi did you run `git rm -r --cached .`?