# Mistakenly added big folder (`.terraform`) to git, committed, then put to `.gitignore`, but still wants to send big folder to origin

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I added a big folder (`.terraform`) with `git add .`, and then committed.

Then I realized that's not a good idea. Edited `.gitignore`. Committed.

Then realized that when pushing to origin, it was still pushing big files. 
Looked around and found this:
[Git still adds and tracks folders marked in .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418718/git-still-adds-and-tracks-folders-marked-in-gitignore)

So did `git rm -r --cached .` , added back in everything.

My index seems to be clean.
But when I do `git push origin branch`, it seems to want to upload all the big files still, as it takes a lot of time, and finally finishes with

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 4949224cd016eea505329480a9359f56
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File scripts/terraform/testing/.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v2.62.0_x4 is 146.95 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

How do I clean up this so that pushing doesn't push the big files which I want ignored anyways?

`.gitignore` looks like this:

`1 **/.terraform/*`

Comment: Thanks @mx0 but the link suggests exactly the same as the link I posted in my Q, which I did, but still I am getting the same error as above

Comment: If you only have 2 new commits (big one and gitignore) the do `git reset @~2` and add everything except big folder again.